# Tensorflow: Gradient Calculation from Input to Output

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, tensorflow-gradient

I would like to calculate the gradients of the output of a neural network with respect to the input. I have the following tensors:

```
Input: (num_timesteps, features)

Output: (num_timesteps, 1)
```

For the gradients from the inputs to the entire output vector I can use the following:

```
tf.gradients(Output, Input)
```

Since I would like to compute the gradients for every single timesample I would like to calculate

```
tf.gradients(Output[i], Input)
```

for every `i`.

What is the best way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

First up, I suppose you mean the gradient of `Output` *with respect to* the `Input`.

Now, [the result](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients) of both of these calls:

- `dO = tf.gradients(Output, Input)`
- `dO_i = tf.gradients(Output[i], Input)` (for any valid `i`)

will be a list with a single element - a tensor with **the same shape** as `Input`, namely a `[num_timesteps, features]` matrix. Also, if you sum all matrices `dO_i` (over all valid `i`) is exactly the matrix `dO`.

With this in mind, back to your question. In many cases, individual rows from the `Input` are independent, meaning that `Output[i]` is calculated only from `Input[i]` and doesn't know other inputs (typical case: batch processing without batchnorm). If that is your case, then `dO` is going to give you all individual components `dO_i` at once.

This is because each `dO_i` matrix is going to look like this:

```
[[  0.   0.   0.]
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 ...
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 [ xxx  xxx  xxx]     <- i-th row
 [  0.   0.   0.]
 ...
 [  0.   0.   0.]]
```

All rows are going to be `0`, except for the `i`-th one. So just by computing one matrix `dO`, you can easily get every `dO_i`. This is very efficient.

However, if that's not your case and all `Output[i]` depend on all inputs, there's no way to extract individual `dO_i` just from their sum. You have no other choice other than calculate each gradient separately: just iterate over `i` and execute `tf.gradients`.